# How To migrate Topics from one Apache kafka cluster to another Kafka cluster without prefix names in target cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, migration, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I'm testing migrate data from one apache kafka cluster of version 2.8.2 to another kafka cluster  using mirror maker 2.0 .
But am Able to replicate topics with prefix of source cluster in target cluster.

My current config "mirrormaker2.properties"

```
clusters = A, B
A.bootstrap.servers = *.*:9092
B.bootstrap.servers = 172.20.100.121:9092

# enable and configure individual replication flows
A->B.enabled = true

# regex which defines which topics gets replicated. For eg "foo-.*"
A->B.topics = .*

#B->A.enabled = true
#B->A.topics = .*

# Setting replication factor of newly created remote topics
replication.factor=1
checkpoints.topic.replication.factor=1
heartbeats.topic.replication.factor=1
offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor=1

# The replication factor for connect internal topics "mm2-configs.B.internal", "mm2-    offsets.B.internal" and
# "mm2-status.B.internal"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to         ensure availability such as 3.
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.replication.factor=1

# customize as needed
replication.policy.separator :
source.cluster.alias :
target.cluster.alias :
```

Comment: Your last three lines are missing equal signs, so that's not a valid property file